# Paying a Brazil visa overstay fine upon reentry without paperwork

Tags: visas, overstaying, brazil

Last year I overstayed my visa in Brazil by one day and received a fine of R$100 upon departure. I was subsequently robbed and lost the paperwork related to my fine, but at the time I was told that I needed to pay the fine from outside Brazil before returning. Lacking the instructions and paperwork, this is no longer possible.

[This guide](https://braziliangringo.com/tourist-visa-brazil/#Overstaying_a_Brazilian_Tourist_Visa) says that it is possible to pay the fine at the airport upon arrival, however it specifically states that I should arrive during working hours and with the original paperwork.

The only flights from the UK arrive outside working hours and I no longer have the paperwork. I can of course ensure that I have the correct cash for the fine.

My questions are, has anyone successfully re-entered Brazil in my circumstances and what was their experience? If I take the risk, what is the probability of being put straight back on a flight home? Are there any alternative approaches to dealing with the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try contacting the Brazilian embassy in your country to see if they have any advice?

Comment: I have emailed the consulate in the UK but no response as yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to pay a fine once. I didn't bring any money with me, so the Policia Federal guards took me to the airport area and I could withdraw the money from the ATM and pay the fine. Once paid, I received my 90 visa free entry.

Very easy and they were all very friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Did you pay the money directly to the border guard, or did you have to visit a bank to do it? One possible concern I have heard about is that if you arrive outside working hours it's not possible to pay the fine.